# Django- How can I display the correct data from similar objects inside a nested for-loop from my template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Inside my `DetailView`, I have 3 objects that are very similar with slight differences in the what is being filtered.

```
# views.py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):    

    # all sales for all line items (products) with a specified title
    sales = Sales.objects.filter(publication__title=self.object)

    # filters print sales for a specified title
    print_sales = Sales.objects.filter(publicaton__title=self.object, line_item=1) 

    # filters digital sales for a specified title
    digital_sales = Sales.objects.filter(publicaton__title=self.object, line_item=2)
```

Ideally, I would like to display a table that has all sales separated by product and month like so:

```
| Month           | Print Sales | Digital Sales |
| --------------- | ----------- | ------------- |
| January         | 2,000       | 3,000         |
| February        | 1,000       | 2,000         |
| --------------- | ----------- | ------------- |
| Total:          | 3,000       | 5,000         |
| Combined Total: |             | 8,000         |
```

However, I have not been able to figure out a way to properly format the table AND provide the correct filtered data within my template. The snippet below displays the properly formatted table (similar to above) but with the combined sales data displaying in each month.

```
{% for item in sales %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ item.issue }}</td>
    {% for obj in print_sales %}
        <td>{{ obj.net_sales}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for obj in digital_sales%}
        <td>{{ obj.net_sales}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}


##### output ######

| Month           | Print Sales | Digital Sales |
| --------------- | ----------- | ------------- |
| January         | 3,000       | 5,000         |
| February        | 3,000       | 5,000         |
| --------------- | ----------- | ------------- |
| Total:          | 3,000       | 5,000         |
| Combined Total: |             | 8,000         |
```

So far all of the adjustments I have made to the template and the tags just breaks the table design.

Here is an abbreviated version of my models:

```
# models.py

class LineItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...) # print sales, digital sales... 
    ...

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    ...  

class Sales(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, ...)
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue, ...)  # gets each month from the Issue model
    line_item = models.ForeignKey(LineItem, ...)
    net_sales = models.DecimalField(...)
    ...
```

What can I change in my template or view that would be a better approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are using for loop

```
 {% for item in sales %}
```

causing both the print_sales and digital sales to execute two times.
Here both of them might be returing only one object each.
try this:

```
 {% for item in sales %}
   <tr>
   <td>{{ item.issue }}</td>
   </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% for obj in print_sales %}
  <tr>
  <td>{{ obj.net_sales}}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
{% for obj in digital_sales%}
   <tr> <td>{{ obj.net_sales}}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```